# Loss of quality when using embed_fonts

Tags: r, r-markdown, ghostscript

I have an issue when I embed fonts via GhostScript in a PDF generated by RMarkdown.
Here are my lines of code:

```
rmarkdown::render("myfile.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = "output.pdf")
embed_fonts("output.pdf", outfile = "output_with_fonts.pdf")
```

Here are before/after excerpts of the pdf files:

[image: Before:]

[image: After:]

You can see that the red dots have been transformed into stars and the solid lines around the bars into dashed lines.

Also I noticed that the size of the second file is about a half/a third of the first one.
I tried to add some options to GhostScript but without success.

Can someone help me on this?

Regards,
Fabien

Comment: You need to publish the file you are sending to Ghostscript, and the command line being used to drive Ghostscript before I can offer any suggestions. Have you read https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm ? When you produce a new PDF file from an original, you are not 'embedding fonts' and that document explains why.

Comment: Thanks @KenS for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot provide the pdf as it contains sensible data. It is strictly the output of RMarkdown. Regarding the command line, I use embed_fonts provided by the extrafonts package.

Comment: Perhaps you can manufacture a file which is not private. Without an example to look at I doubt there is anything anyone can do to help you. I have no idea what 'embed_fonts' does in R, because I know nothing about R :-) If you think it uses Ghostscript, then perhaps someone can tell you how to find out **how** it uses Ghostscript, and then I could help further.

Comment: I was able to get the command line:
-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dAutoRotatePAges=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite

I saw that the vectorized figures (points, lines, areas...) are the one which are compressed. So is there a way to remove the compression for svg?

Comment: There is no SVG. Ghostscript doesn't read SVG so you can't be sending SVG to it, and the pdfwrite device produces PDF files. I can't see anywhere that involves SVG. Note that the command line there doesn't do anything about embedding fonts. If you wanted that you should set -dEmbedAllFonts=true, what you have is the default which won't embed the base 14 fonts (unless they are in the input stream). I think you;re going to need to send the input file as well. If you can't share the file, then you'll have to make one which shows the same problem and you can share. I can't work in the dark :-(

Comment: Oh, in case it isn't clear, I need the input file being sent to Ghostscript, please don't send me an R file because I won't be able to do anything with it